# Update and display column which Controller user has "touched"

Tags: laravel

I'm currently working on a feature and don't know how to really go about it.

How it goes is when a visitor uses a Model/Controller, they should be able to store this value inside of the database. Like in a polymorphic way, they should be able to access the paramaters.

For example, a user visiting a thread will have a stored value of App\Thread, and a user would be able to retrieve those thread values. "User was last seen visiting thread xyz".

I will think about this, but to honest, I don't know how to approach it, so any help hinting towards the way to achieve this would be awesome! Thank you for your assistance in advance! I will use the ideas to work towards this tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to approach this would be to create a table to record all the visits by the user - say a table called `visits`

```php
//Migration schema for visits table
Schema::create('visits', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('visitable_id');
    $table->string('visitable_type');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
}
```

Then you can have a relation between visits and User

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public function visits()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Visit::class);
    }
    
    //... rest of the class code
}

class Visit extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    
    public function visitable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    //... rest of the class code
}


class Thread extends Model
{
    public function visits()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Visit::class, 'visitable');
    }

    //... rest of the class code
}
```

Then every time a user visits a thread, the show controller can create an entry in the visits table for the logged in user.

```php
public function show(Thread $thread)
{
    $thread->visits()->create(['user_id' => auth()->id()]);

    //... rest of the method code
}
```